# Cast player to Chromecast or android TV

Tags: casting, media-player, chromecast, android-tv

I have a html5 based player in my project.
I want to allow my users to cast it to their TVs.

I find myself totally lost.

1. What is the difference between casting to Chromecast and android TV?
   Do I need different implementation/application for each?
   Or if I develop for Chromecast it will work for smart TVs as well?
   If I don't want to implement a custom receiver, can I only implement a sender application?
2. Other then apple, are there smart TVs that are not android based?
   How is casting implemented with them?
3. If I have a hybrid application that runs on ios and on android, what sender application do I need? Do I need a different one for ios and android? Or for hybrid  I can also build a hybrid  sender?

If there are a simple tutorial for dummies' I would love a link

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify on terminology before diving in, a Cast Sender is the app that is controlling the video (e.g., your app on a mobile device) and a Cast Receiver is what's actually playing the video typically on a larger device such as a TV.

> What is the difference between casting to Chromecast and android TV? Do I need different implementation/application for each? Or if I develop for Chromecast it will work for smart TVs as well?

For normal usage, there's no difference in implementation; it's just a case of where the Cast Receiver is running. You can *optionally* choose to have a native Android TV application as the receiver, which is called [Cast Connect](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/introducing-cast-connect-android-tv.html), but that is a relatively new feature. Your standard Cast Receiver can run on a variety of hardware and you don't care about the hardware specifics, just the capabilities (e.g., for determining FHD vs 4K).

> If I don't want to implement a custom receiver, can I only implement a sender application?

You have to have a Cast Receiver, but there are two options. You can either implement a Styled Web Receiver (sounds like that's what makes sense in your case and isn't much work) or you can implement a custom receiver. Both are covered on the [Web Receiver Overview page](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver).

> Other then apple, are there smart TVs that are not android based? How is casting implemented with them?

There are a variety of smart TV platforms aside from Android TV and tvOS, including Tizen, WebOS, and others. Your Cast Receiver will work on any of them that support Cast and you don't need to have any custom logic to support them individually.

> If I have a hybrid application that runs on ios and on android, what sender application do I need? Do I need a different one for ios and android? Or for hybrid I can also build a hybrid sender?

You need to implement the [Android Sender](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender) and [iOS Sender](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender) apps separately.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Samsung TV, there's a extension lib called SmartView SDK.

> With the Samsung Smart View SDK, you can develop mobile apps that can stream multimedia content from mobile devices to Samsung Smart TVs.

You can refer document here:

https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/design/smart-view-sdk.html

https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/extension-libraries/smart-view-sdk/download.html

And official demo here:

https://github.com/SamsungDForum/SmartViewSDKCastVideo